# How to link jsp file to another jsp in eclipse?

Tags: java, jsp

I have created 2 jsp files in the same directory and I want to link a word(Progress) in a.jsp to Progress.jsp page. In order to do that, I have

The code is as below:

`<tr><td></td>
<td style = "text-decoration: underline">Progress</td>
                <td href = "Progress.jsp"> </td>
        </tr>`

However, the "href" cannot be used because it says that "href" is undefined atrribute name.

And to trigger the word to another page, the code is as below:

```
$(".toDet").on("click",function(){          
        var toPage = "";
        var lclick = "";
        var progress = $(this).closest('td').find('.progress').val(); 
        if(this.className=="toDet"){ //redirect page
            toPage = "Progress.jsp";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `td` tag is used for table cells. It has no `href` attribute. The `a` (anchor) tag is used to create links and has the `href` attribute. Try generating:

```
<td><a href="Progress.jsp">link text</a></td>
```